Geometric visulalization of Cosine Similarity
I have calculated the cosine similarity between two documents in a very basic way by using TF-IDF vectorization in Python.
But I want to visualize the documents as a vectorized graph in a 3D space. Like this:

Here's the code I used for calculating cosine similarity:
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Sample documents
documents = [
    "This is a sample document.",
    "This document is another example."
]

# Vectorizing the documents
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidf_matrix = vectorizer.fit_transform(documents)

# Calculating cosine similarity
cosine_sim = cosine_similarity(tfidf_matrix[0:1], tfidf_matrix[1:2])
print("Cosine Similarity:", cosine_sim)


Since your vocabulary (unique words in all documents) is more than 3, it is hard to visualize it in the format you have presented in the image. However, you can use t-SNE to reduce your document embeddings to 3 (or even 2) dimensions and visualize them. The code would roughly look like:
from sklearn.manifold import TSNE
doc_embedded = TSNE(n_components=2, learning_rate='auto',
                  init='random', perplexity=1).fit_transform(tfidf_matrix)

doc_embedded[i] will be the 2-dimensional embedding of document i, and you can visualize them together in 2D plane.
You can understand the details of how t-SNE works and how it preserves the structure in embeddings here.

Thank you for your message, but I want to visualise it in the 3D plane.
